# Prove that in set theory $A-B = A - (A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that in set theory $A-B = A - (A \cap B)$

Please give me a hint.

Let $x\in A-B \implies x\in A~ and ~x \notin B\implies x\in A ~and (x\in A ~and~ x \notin B)\implies x\in A - (A \cap B)$

Comment: hint: consider an arbitrary element $x$ in the left hand side. Argue that it is in the right-hand side. Now consider an arbitrary element $y$ in the right hand side. Argue that it is in the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of $A-B$, namely $A\cap \overline{B}$, the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_complements), the [Distributive laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra), the [Complement laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) and the [Identity laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra).

$$A-(A\cap B)=A\cap\overline{A\cap B}$$

$$=A\cap(\overline{A}\cup \overline{B})=(A\cap \overline{A})\cup(A\cap\overline{B})$$

$$=\varnothing\cup(A\cap \overline{B})=A\cap \overline{B}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $B=(A\cap B) \cup (A^c\cap B)$ but the set in the second paranthesis has no intersection with $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in A - B$. Then, $x$ is in $A$, but $x$ is not in $B$. It follows that $x$ is not in both $A$ and $B$, otherwise $x$ would be in $B$. Hence, $x \in A - (A \cap B)$, so $A-B \subset A - (A\cap B)$. Can you do the other direction using this as a model?